# Ubuntu 20.04 when I tried to install RabbitMQ it showing this error

Tags: rabbitmq

I followed this website to install RabbitMQ https://attacomsian.com/blog/install-rabbitmq-macos-ubuntu

On the 5th step where it install RabbitMq, When I run the command I get this error

```
rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-08-20 10:11:27 IST; 5ms ago
    Process: 361473 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 361473 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I run sudo apt update, this error is showing

```
    E: The repository 'http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: The command in "step 5" of the link you posted would not produce that output unless you have chopped it up. You should include the full unredacted output as well as the actual command that you are running. Did you update the list of available software and is your system up-to-date?  These are prerequisites for installing any new software. You should include the output of `sudo apt update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the official documentation:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-quick-start-packagecloud

with a simple script, you can easily install rabbitmq on ubuntu.

for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

sudo apt-get install curl gnupg apt-transport-https -y

## Team RabbitMQ's main signing key
curl -1sLf "https://keys.openpgp.org/vks/v1/by-fingerprint/0A9AF2115F4687BD29803A206B73A36E6026DFCA" | sudo gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/com.rabbitmq.team.gpg
## Launchpad PPA that provides modern Erlang releases
curl -1sLf "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xf77f1eda57ebb1cc" | sudo gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/net.launchpad.ppa.rabbitmq.erlang.gpg
## PackageCloud RabbitMQ repository
curl -1sLf "https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/gpgkey" | sudo gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/io.packagecloud.rabbitmq.gpg

## Add apt repositories maintained by Team RabbitMQ
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list <<EOF
## Provides modern Erlang/OTP releases
##
## "focal" as distribution name should work for any reasonably recent Ubuntu or Debian release.
## See the release to distribution mapping table in RabbitMQ doc guides to learn more.
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/net.launchpad.ppa.rabbitmq.erlang.gpg] http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/ubuntu focal main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/net.launchpad.ppa.rabbitmq.erlang.gpg] http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/ubuntu focal main

## Provides RabbitMQ
##
## "focal" as distribution name should work for any reasonably recent Ubuntu or Debian release.
## See the release to distribution mapping table in RabbitMQ doc guides to learn more.
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/io.packagecloud.rabbitmq.gpg] https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ focal main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/io.packagecloud.rabbitmq.gpg] https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu/ focal main
EOF

## Update package indices
sudo apt-get update -y

## Install Erlang packages
sudo apt-get install -y erlang-base \
                        erlang-asn1 erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-ftp erlang-inets \
                        erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-public-key \
                        erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssl \
                        erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tftp erlang-tools erlang-xmerl

## Install rabbitmq-server and its dependencies
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y --fix-missing
```

and ..

```
root@ubuntu-focal:/home/vagrant# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@ubuntu-focal ...
Runtime

OS PID: 4038
OS: Linux
Uptime (seconds): 14
Is under maintenance?: false
RabbitMQ version: 3.9.4
Node name
```

Comment: I forgot it, you recalled me, and it fixed my issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of an environment variable reload, in file

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/rabbitmq-server.postinst`,

the line:

```
. /etc/profile
```

You could comment it out and do: `apt install --fix-broken -y`